# Adobe InDesign templates and design templates' cross-compatibility

Tags: templates, adobe-indesign

Do Adobe InDesign templates only work in InDesign? 
What are the options for design template formats, and what programs do they work in?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, InDesign templates only work in InDesign. In general, any program that offers a template feature uses a proprietary file type that can't be parsed by other programs. I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but I will say that transferring between various parts of the Adobe suite is possible depending on the file formats you're working with and what your end goal is.